# Linq select time with date + 1

Tags: c#, linq

In my SQL 2008 R2, I have this table:

[image]

I have create the LINQ syntax to select all hours that greater than computer hour:

```
 public IList<LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE> Get_All_Obj(string CLIENT_ID)
        {
            try
            {
                IList<LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE> LesListe;
                using (Soft8Exp_ClientEntities oEntite_T = new Soft8Exp_ClientEntities())
                {
                    int The_Hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
                    var query = from o in oEntite_T.LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE where o.CLIENT_ID == CLIENT_ID && o.HORRAIRE > new TimeSpan(The_Hour, 00/*minutes*/, 00/*seconds*/) select o;
                    LesListe = query.ToList();
                }
                return LesListe;
            }
            catch (Exception excThrown)
            {
                throw new Exception("Err_02", excThrown);
            }
        }
```

and it is work fine:

- when the hour computer is `08:00` then it return `12:00` and `19:00`,
- when the hour computer is `13:00` then it return `19:00`.

But now I want to change the program that look at the date also:

- when the hour computer is `08:00` then it return `12:00` and `19:00` and `05:00`.
- when the hour computer is `13:00` then it return `19:00` and `05:00`.
- when the hour computer is `20:00` then it return `05:00`.

Any idea ?

i have tried like this:

```
 DateTime The_Date = DateTime.Now.Date;
                    var query = from o in oEntite_T.LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE where o.CLIENT_ID == CLIENT_ID && The_Date.Add(o.HORRAIRE) > DateTime.Now select o;
                    LesListe = query.ToList(
```

);

but unfortunately it not work

Comment: You have no date information in your table. Is this in another column?

Comment: no, just take the date now as a reference

Comment: I can't follow the logic. You want all hours greater than the actual hour, but 5:00 is always returned. How comes that?

Comment: Can you explain why, in the `13:00` case, `05:00` is returned but not `12:00`?

Comment: Yes, please explain the logic. Also, when something "does not work" please explain what that means. Is there an exception message, not the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = oEntite_T.LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE
                .Where(o => o.CLIENT_ID == CLIENT_ID &&
                      (o.HORRAIRE > DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay || 
                       o.HORRAIRE.Hours == 5));
```

That would make the method behave like you'd like. Though I don't understand, why you want 5:00 returned, even though it is actually smaller than `DateTime.Now = 13:00`.

I think your table lacks date information, which makes the logic broken.